# Nested Forloop with Remove method and If condition using LINQ

Tags: c#, jquery, linq, lambda, nested

I want to convert the below code to LINQ or Lambda expression.

```
for (int indexprod = 0; indexprod < tempProduct.Count; indexprod++)
{
  for (int index = 0; index < tempProduct[indexprod].Prices.Count; index++)
  {
    if (tempProduct[indexprod].Prices[index].Term == null || tempProduct[indexprod].Prices[index].Term == 0)
    {
      tempProduct[indexprod].Prices.Remove(tempProduct[indexprod].Prices[index]);
      index--;
    }
  }

  if (tempProduct[indexprod].Prices.Count == 0)
  {
    tempProduct.Remove(tempProduct[indexprod]);
    indexprod--;
  }
}
```

I tried to do this:

```
List<Product> tempprod1= (from p in products
                     from pr in p.Prices
                     where pr.Term == 0
                     select p).ToList<Product>();
```

but not able to figure out how to remove the price element when pr.Term!0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you have:

```
tempProduct
  .ForEach(p => p.Prices.RemoveAll(price => (price.Term ?? 0)==0 ))
  .RemoveAll(p => p.Prices.Count == 0);
```

Hope this helps. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Would this not work and be more concise...

```
tempProduct.RemoveAll(p => p.Prices.Count == 0);
```

Comment: Thanks for response, but this will not work, I have to remove all the products which have Price.Term==0

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove price element if Term = 0 . Below is the query

```
tempProduct.ForEach(p=> p.Prices.Remove(p.Prices.ToList().ToList().Where(x => x.Term == 0).FirstOrDefault()));
```